# Add template to widgets un magento

Tags: magento

I am integrate custom template to widget but its doesn't show the template data. below is my code

community/Sample/Productslider/etc/widget.xml

```
<widgets>
<productslider_bestseller type="productslider/bestseller" translate="product slider option" module="productslider">
    <name>Best Seller Product</name>
    <description type="desc">Enable the Best Seller Product Widget</description>
<parameters>
  <template>
            <required>1</required>
            <visible>1</visible>
            <label>Template</label>
            <type>select</type>
     <values>
       <best-seller translate="label">
                    <value>productslider/best-seller.phtml</value>
                    <label>Best Seller</label>
                </best-seller>
     </values>
     </template>
   </parameters>
   </productslider_bestseller>
</widgets>
```

community/Sample/Productslider/Block/Bestseller.php

```
class Sample_Productslider_Block_Bestseller extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract implements Mage_Widget_Block_Interface
{

protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
}
protected function _toHtml()
{
    $pageTitle = '';
    $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
    if ($headBlock) {
        $pageTitle = $headBlock->getTitle();
    }

    $html = "test";
    $this->assign('best-seller', $html);
    return parent::_toHtml();
}
}
```

fronted/base/default/template/productslider/best-seller.phtml

```
echo $html;
```

It show blank page in front when i include widget in cms page.
Any one can help me to find out the issue in my code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To me your issue consists in extending Mage_Core_Block_Abstract in which _toHtml method return a void string.

Just set your template in your constructor and extends Mage_Core_Block_Template instead of Mage_Core_Block_Abstract

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a template to a block via the constructor (example taken from core file : `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/State.php:43`)

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->setTemplate('catalog/layer/state.phtml');
}
```

So you would have to do something like this in your *__contruct*

```
$this->setTemplate('productslider/best-seller.phtml');
```

But what you seems to have trouble with is passing data to this template ?

Then, make is as you would in any other template : 
In your block :

```
public function getSomeExtraHtml(){
    return 'test';    
}
```

In the template :

```
<?php echo $this->getSomeExtraHtml() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the template in your Block Class

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
   $this->setTemplate('my_module/widget.phtml');
   return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

Create a folder under
app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/my_module and add your html file